# How to determine how evenly distributed numbers are on a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a set of numbers and want to determine how evenly distributed these numbers are.

E. g.:

$E_1 = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}$

$E_2 = {2, 3,6, 7,10}$

$E_1$ is more evenly distributed than  $E_2$ as the differences between one element to its neighbors are always the same.

My questions are:

1. What is the correct mathematical term for this *being evenly distributed* respectively is there a dedicated part of mathematics that deals with this question?
2. What is a canonical way of calculating this ***amount of being evenly distributed*** for simple cases like the one above or if my numbers are rational numbers?

Comment: This sounds like a simpler version of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3320288).

Comment: There is a quantity called the *discrepancy* of a set, which may be just what you want. It's often defined for subsets of the unit interval, $[0,1]$, but you can just divide all your elements by ten.